# What is the worlds shortest runway for FAR 23 commuter type aircraft?

Tags: airport

[This article](http://www.safebee.com/photoblogs/travel/5-worlds-shortest-runways) lists the airport at Saba as the worlds shortest runway at 1300 ft. The runway is built on a bit of flat land on the side of the volcano that makes up the island. Nowadays STOL aircraft land here, previously the aircraft had to come in skimming over the wave tops and zoom climb onto the runway.

The Twin Otter [can land here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juancho_E._Yrausquin_Airport). Does Saba really have the shortest runway on earth for FAR 23 commuter type aircraft, or are there any shorter ones?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That would be Out Skerries (IATA: OUK) in [Shetland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shetland) with a 1,195 ft / 364 m runway ([source](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/lists/shortest-airport-runways/outer-skerries/)).

[image]
60°25'30.08" N   0°44'55.93" W

[image]
([Source](https://andysroundtheworldtrip.blogspot.com.eg/2011/05/out-skerries-shetland-as-far-east-as.html))

[image]
([Source](https://andysroundtheworldtrip.blogspot.com.eg/2011/05/out-skerries-shetland-as-far-east-as.html))

Above plane is a [Britten-Norman BN-2 Islander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Britten-Norman_BN-2_Islander), with a stall speed of 35 knots.

> The Britten-Norman BN-2 Islander is a 1960s British light utility aircraft, regional airliner and cargo aircraft. Still in production, the Islander is one of the best-selling commercial aircraft types produced in Europe.